# How to find month no,name from week number using php

Tags: php

How to find month no,name from week number using php

Comment: *(reference)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: But suppose i have week no 50 so i want december(12) as out put –

 
Do u have any idea ????????Thanks in advance

Comment: This is impossible. A week is a span of dates which often corresponds to more than one month.

Comment: @Dan, you are right; However you can say that week 5 of 2010 starts at January (although it ends at February) and PHP will help you doing that really easy using `strtotime()`...

Answer (score 8):

If you have the [ISO week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) number, then to get the month (of the start of the week) you can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) like:

```
// F = full name of month, n = month number without leading zero
echo date('F n', strtotime('2010-W50'));
```

Bear in mind that the ISO week *might not* be the same as your meaning of week, so read on.

If you want to count the whole weeks since January 1<sup>st</sup> of this year (regardless of what day of the week that is) then you could do as [Adnan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438377/how-to-find-month-no-name-from-week-number-using-php/4438424#4438424) mentioned:

```
echo date('F n', strtotime('1 Jan + 50 weeks'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date('F',strtotime('1 January 2010 +50 weeks'));
```

[www.php.net/date](http://www.php.net/date)
[www.php.net/strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at php date() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Here are some good examples:

```
<?php
// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Prints something like: Monday
echo date("l");

// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

// Prints: July 1, 2000 is on a Saturday
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));

/* use the constants in the format parameter */
// prints something like: Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:12:46 UTC
echo date(DATE_RFC822);

// prints something like: 2000-07-01T00:00:00+00:00
echo date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$myDate = "2010-05-12";

$weekNumber = date("W", strtotime($myDate));
```

Just replace the "W" with the value you need. Full reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you have a week number, and want the date from it you can use:

```
date("d m Y", strtotime("1.1.2010 + 30 weeks"));
```

Comment: But suppose i have week no 50 so i want december(12) as out put