# Get month value from week number using php

Tags: php

I am trying to get month value using the week number. Is there a convenient way to get the month value.

I tried the below code. But it not helped me

```
for($i=1;$i<=52;$i++)
echo "$i ). ".$month_val    =  date('m', strtotime("2017W$i"))."<br />";
```

There are already more questions which are getting month or week value from a **date**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find month no,name from week number using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438377/how-to-find-month-no-name-from-week-number-using-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you got the year and the week it is easy done with the PHP native [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

```
echo (new DateTime())->setISODate(2017, 5)->format('m');
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Great, How simple it is